# Solution to this linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So this is my homework :

Let $$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
        2 & 0 & \lambda & 6 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\\$$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}
        1\\
        2\\
        1\\
        \end{pmatrix}\\$

Solution of linear equation system $Ax=b$ for every $\lambda € R$?

My Solution:

I brought the matrix to row echelon Form ==>

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 3 |1\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 2 |0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda-2 & 0 |0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}

For every $\lambda$ $rank(A)=rank(A|b)\\$ 
Which means this  Linear equation system is soluble. But what i m confused is we have for every lambda more Variable then equations so this LES has only infinite solutions? and for example for $\lambda =2\\$

we have $\begin{pmatrix}
        1-x_3-3x_4\\
        2x_4\\
        x_3\\
        x_4\end{pmatrix}\\$

But for every diffrent $\lambda$ we get  different combination of variables for the Solution which is not equal to other infinite solution.So what is incorrect in my solution ?

Comment: Unless $\lambda=2$, that's not reduced row-echelon form, and $x_3$ is not arbitrary, it must be zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so unless lambda =2 the solution is (1-3x4,2x4,0,x4) ?

Comment: Yes, assuming you've done the row reduction correctly --- I didn't check your arithmetic.

Comment: @nbdip: Did you still need an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The $(2,4)$ entry of your reduced matrix should be $-2$ rather than $2$.

Then you distinguish between two cases: Case I, $\lambda =2$; and case II, $\lambda\neq2$.

Case I: $\lambda\neq2$, rank is 3, one free parameter. Write the equations down $x_4=s$ (free parameter):

- $(\lambda -2)x_3=0$ hence $x_3=0$
- $x_2=2s$
- $x_1=1-3s$.

Case II: $\lambda=2$, rank is 2, set two free parameters and solve as before.